# How to disable a grid while work is being done?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I've been trying to disable the grid in my wpf while work is being done and then re-enabling it after it is complete, but so far I have been unsuccessful. Here is my current code that I feel should be accomplishing that:

**XAML Code**

```
 <Button Name="ButtonCompare" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="6" Height="25" Width="80" Click="compare" Margin="0,0,0,7">Compare</Button>
```

**C# Code**

```
    private async Task DoWork()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        });
    }

    private async void compare(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (bu1Valid is false || bu2Valid is false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("A valid backup path has not been entered", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            myDatagrid.IsEnabled = false;
            await DoWork();
            myDatagrid.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
```

So far I've tried using bindings, different events on the button, and events on the grid, but they all have had the same result where all my controls in the grid stay enabled. If I take out the pieces that re-enable the grid, then the grid becomes disabled after the event finishes, but I'm trying to get it to become disabled before it starts the work so the button can't be clicked again while the job is running.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Look into async await

Comment: I have updated my question with the answer provided by paparazzo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example.

```
private async void startButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CancelEnabled = true;
    await start();
}

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    btnTest.IsEnabled = false;
    await Dowork();
    btnTest.IsEnabled = true;
}
private async Task Dowork()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an async call in your DoWork() method.  Putting "await" in front of the call will make sure that the code following the async call does not execute until the call has finished.

```
private async void doWork()
{
        await MakeYourCallHere();
        myDatagrid.IsEnabled = true;
}
```